# Is there a \phantom considering cramped style?

Tags: math-mode, macros

In LaTeX2e, `\phantom` is defined as

```
\def\vphantom{\v@true\h@false\ph@nt}
\def\hphantom{\v@false\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\phantom{\v@true\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\ph@nt{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\mathph@nt
  \else
    \expandafter\makeph@nt
  \fi}
\def\makeph@nt#1{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}\finph@nt}
\def\mathph@nt#1#2{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finph@nt}
\def\finph@nt{%
  \setbox\tw@\null
  \ifv@ \ht\tw@\ht\z@ \dp\tw@\dp\z@\fi
  \ifh@ \wd\tw@\wd\z@\fi \box\tw@}
```

It means that, in math mode,

```
$\sqrt{\phantom{x^2}}$
```

has the same size of

```
$\sqrt{\hbox{$x^2$}}$
```

but differs from

```
$\sqrt{x^2}$
```

since `x^2` in `\sqrt` is in cramped mode.

I know that `mathtools` package provides a `\cramped` macro to solve the problem, but is there an automatical method?

---

Test code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont
$\sqrt{x^A} \sqrt{\hbox{$x^A$}}$

$\sqrt{\phantom{\cramped{x^A}}} \sqrt{\phantom{x^A}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is "no" even with e-tex primitives you can not detect this. Perhaps luatex can jump to the rescue?

With thanks to the commenters, this *should* be possible in luatex

```
\ifnum\mathstyle=\crampedtextstyle
```

or for lualatex

```
\ifnum\luatexmathstyle=\luatexcrampedtextstyle
```

Note that as usual `\over` may cause some complications stopping the math style being detected, see `\Ustack` (`\luatexUstack`) in the luatex manual.

Comment: LuaTeX has `\mathstyle`, but strangely enough it's undefined in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg, so it does thanks, the luatex manual suggests `\ifnum\mathstyle=\crampedtextstyle` ought to work.

Comment: @egreg: all luatex’s new commands are prefixed by `\luatex` in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's the solution. Can you copy the comment into the answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the patch of `\phantom` for LuaLaTeX, based on David Carlisle's answer:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ifluatex
\makeatletter

\def\ph@nt{%
  \ifmmode
    \ifodd\luatexmathstyle % 1,3,5,7 for cramped styles
      \def\reserved@a{\cramped}%
    \else
      \let\reserved@a\relax
    \fi
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\mathph@nt
  \else
    \expandafter\makeph@nt
  \fi}

\def\mathph@nt#1#2{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1\reserved@a{#2}$}\finph@nt}

\makeatother
\fi
```

Then `\phantom` can detect cramped math styles